# NullPointerException on .insert() method

Tags: javascript, junit4, drools

I'm following a guide to get started in Drools 6.5, so I don't understand 100% of what I'm writing, but I'm getting a NullPointerException error on my .insert() method in my test case class. I've followed the guide in the Drools.org documentation to the tee but according to the documentation my code should be working.

I was thinking maybe the documentation is outdated and the method has been changed/depreciated, but I can't find any similar reported issues.

```
package Basic1;

import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;
import org.kie.api.runtime.StatelessKieSession;
import util.KnowledgeSessionHelper;

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public class FirstRuleTest {
    StatelessKieSession sessionStateless = null;
    KieSession sessionStateful = null;
    static KieContainer kieContainer;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass(){
        kieContainer = KnowledgeSessionHelper.createRuleBase();
    }

    @Test
    public void firstTest(){
        sessionStateful = KnowledgeSessionHelper.getStatefulKnowledgeSession(kieContainer,"ksession-rules");
        Account a = new Account();
        sessionStateful.insert(a); // this is throwing the error when I test with JUnit 4
        sessionStateful.fireAllRules();
    }
}
```

P.S. I hope it's alright that I just pasted all that in, the file isn't that long and I thought it was important to show everything that had been imported and defined.

Comment: Does the error message include more details such as where inside 'insert' is the error thrown?

Comment: No, it just says that line unfortunately.

Comment: Ah, hang on, it's saying I don't have the Javadoc attached. How would I go about acquiring and attaching the Javadoc?

Comment: Is your `sessionStateful` variable null?

Comment: Try and use the last version of Drools

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing the kmodule.xml configuration file in your project resources. You can find the details about it in the documentation - http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.2.0.CR2/drools-docs/html/KIEChapter.html#KIEBuildingSection.